# How to keep a chunk of text aligned with an image that's size is variable?

Tags: html, css

So, I'm trying to build a site that features various different sized images, one at a time, that are centered and size constrained by a parent div, then resized to preserve their ratio.

```css
#grandparent {
 display: block;
 position: fixed;
        width: 70vw;
        height: 85vh;
        top: 10vh;
        left: 15vw;
 }
 
.parent {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 width: 100%; 
 height: 70vh;
 }
  
.resizedimage {
 max-width: 100%;
 max-height: 100%;
 display: block;
 margin: auto;
 }
```

```html
<div id="grandparent">
 <div class="parent">
  <img src="1.jpg" class="imageprime">
     <div class="description">Words<br>more words</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I want the description below to stick below the bottom left corner of the image, which it currently does when max-width is the one being constrained, but when max-height is being constrained, it moves past the left of the image. I can't figure out how to keep them in line!

All the methods I've seen revolve around moving a container div to 50% then padding back to -50%, or something like that. But as I depend on the image dictating the width and height dynamically, I don't know how to translate that to a container div, or just to the text below!

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple: you need a container that will be sized by image in it with `position: relative` and your description should have `position: absolute` so it will be positioned against container which, in its turn will be sized by image. Something like this:

```css
#grandparent {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    width: 70vw;
    height: 85vh;
    top: 10vh;
    left: 15vw;
}

.parent {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70vh;
}

.image-container {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}
.resizedimage {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
.description {
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  bottom: 5px;
  
}
```

```html
    <div id="grandparent">
     <div class="parent">
        <div class="image-container">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/347508/000000.png" class="resizedimage">
         <div class="description">Words<br>more words</div>
        </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Oo, this almost works! But now the max-height stops constraining it, unless I get it image-container to pass it down, but then it stops centering– it left aligns to the grandparent.

Comment: It really depends on what effect you want to get. For example if you want outer container to keep size and image container to center against it - you can apply `max-height` to image container. Or you may want to apply height constraint to outermost container if you want its size to be controlled by image. Centering of outermost container can be achieved easily by using `display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center`. You can stretch your outermost container to whole viewport - it will result into perfectly centered item. But exact answer requires more information.